# Limit of Rows sqlsrv_fetch_array(). Doesn't return all rows

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a problem with the `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` function. I have a SQL Server database with 60k rows and I need to read it.

The problem that I have is: When `sqlsrv_fetch_array` arrive to the result 381, it stops and the rest of results are not returned.

I'm using simple code to print the number of the row, just like this:

```
$sql10 = "SELECT * FROM Articles";
$count=0;
$stmt10 = sqlsrv_query( $conn2, $sql10 ,array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'keyset' ));
echo "<h3>Number of articles: ".sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt10 )."</h3>";
while( $row10 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt10, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $count++;
    echo $count;
}
```

I get correctly the number of articles with sqlsrv_num_rows:

```
Number of articles: 60591
```

But the while loop stops when arrive to the 381 item.

Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: What is the result if you execute the statement without `$options` parameter - `$stmt10 = sqlsrv_query( $conn2, $sql10 ,array())`?

Comment: Hello, if I remove the $options i get the same result, but sqlsrv_num_rows don't return any value of the quantity of rows. I get result up to 381

Comment: Well, the PHP script is correct. What is the value of `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` and how long does the script execute?

Comment: Hello, I have max_execution_time = 30 on my php.ini, but I don't know how long does the script execute, because never made it to the final, always finish on the 381 item

Comment: It takes approximately 2 seconds to display the 381 results, but never arrive to the 60k result

Comment: I updated max_execution_time to 5000 but happend the same, only 381 results are returned

Comment: Any errors (`echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);`) after the `while` loop?

Comment: Yes! it returns the next array:
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01004
            [SQLSTATE] => 01004
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
        )

)`

Comment: Do you have any `varchar` columns with lehgth > 4000?

Comment: Yes! I see in the DB there are some rows defined as longest varchar, like 7500 or 7000.  Can be this a problem?

Comment: I discovered something, there is a field Varchar[100] , the name of the article. If this field is too long (about 90-100 char) then return me error, if I edit this name and do it tiny, then the error disapear.. Why is happening this?